# How to loop through categories posted by user in all listings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display all of the categories a user on my site has posted in. This is how my models are set up: A user is able to create many listings. This is a one to many relation. A listing is able to have multiple categories, and categories have multiple listings (there are multiple listings with the same category). How do I show all categories a user has listed? I have tried

```
<% @user.listings.each.unique.categories do |category| %>
<li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

as well as

```
<% @user.listings.categories do |category| %>
<li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

Any recommendations on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do directly like this, if you have has_many through inside user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings
  has_many :categories, through: :listings
end
```

and then you can do

```
<% @user.categories do |category| %>
  <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can form a list of categories

```
<% categories = @user.listings.flat_map { |l| l.categories }.uniq %>

<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
```

Or configure relationship between `User` and `Category` with `through`

Comment: Is it better to use .distinct instead of .uniq? Not sure if there is any advantage there.